# Brother DCP-8045D not scanning on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, scanner, brother

I've been trying to install a Brother DCP-8045D on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
The error I get at the moment is "unable to start scanner" unlike the "unable to connect" error I had earlier.

As such so far I have copied `/usr/lib64/sane` to `/usr/lib/sane`, 
installed libsane-extras
and added the two lines:

```
#Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes" to /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
```

`scanimage --test` gives me:

```
scanimage: rounded value of br-x from 212 to 211.981
scanimage: rounded value of br-y from 355.6 to 355.567
scanimage: sane_start: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Have you installed the scanner drivers? http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp8045d_all&os=128

Comment: yes i have installed the drivers using the driver install tool

Comment: it appears the device is not supported by sane atm http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-BROTHER in fact it is not even listed as unsupported.....

Comment: hmm it appears that this particular printer does have 3 penguins on https://openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-DCP-8045D 